# Is OPcache a plus if HTTP caching is enabled?

Tags: php, performance, caching, opcache

I have been reading about general concepts in PHP performance and what could be done to improve it. When developing websites and it's the time to go live I use HTTP caching and maybe a CDN (depends on traffic). Now that made me wonder if OPcache would be useful since I already use HTTP caching - page caching.

Definition of OPcache:

> OPcache improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script
>   bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load
>   and parse scripts on each request.

Is OPcache a plus if a http caching is enabled? I think i miss the point somewhere.

Comment: The reverse argument is also valid, why wouldn't it be? If you cache both is there any downside?

Also consider things that may not be running via HTTP like cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP caching is way different then PHP Opcache.
HTTP caching will cache static results on the client side. This could be for example images, scripts, and pages.

Opcaching will cache precompiled PHP scripts. This will make execution of scripts which are unable to be stored on the client. Think of a my account page for example.

So in short yes. Opcaching will make your PHP execution faster. Since it stores precompiled PHP files. HTTP caching will only help you with static results/pages.

Since you're working on speeding up your PHP performance it might also be good to take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: HTTP caching on the client side? Pretty sure he means caching his output from PHP rather than client side caching of assets. Maybe OP can clarify?

Comment: @JackWilko I thought OP meant cache-control headers. Would be nice to have this clarified.

Comment: Yes, I meant Page Caching, cache files on client's side so he doesn't need to request them again from the server. @JackWilko

Comment: Okay than if you meant client side caching, my answer is still relevant. You should enable opcache in my opinion.

Comment: @Antonios Tsimourtos Page Caching and browser caching are 2 different things. Page Caching means before you serve a page you cache the results on the server and re-serve them if the same page / data / whatever is requested. Browser caching is the server telling the browser to keep a copy of a file and to use it again later if needed, therefore saving the browser from sending a request to the server for it again. Either way just stick OP caching on, if it makes any positive change at all then what's the harm.